# How to get HttpContext from service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httprequest, httpcontext

I have requirement to add in a header on each request to a service a header MyHeader. MyHeader is the jwt  I have received when the user is logging on.

I tried to read it from HttpContext.Request.Headers.
I am trying to access it in my service. I could get the result in the controller but not on the Service layer. Can anyone help me to get the same on service class.

I'm using Asp.net core

Comment: i want to call a different service(Odata service in in an axway endpoint) from my application , there for authorizing this JWT token is used.

Comment: in `asp.net core` we have `IHttpContextAccessor` to get access to an `HttpContext` if available. You need to register for it first in the `ConfigureServices` by using `services.AddHttpContext()`.

Comment: @KingKing my query is is it ppossible to access HttpContext on service class not in the controller. is it possible to share an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Startup#ConfigureServices:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

In your service class:

```
public class YourServiceClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    ...

    // constructor
    public YourServiceClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ...)
    {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
      ...
    }

    public void YourServiceMethod() 
    {
      var headers = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
      ...
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Would be worth registering scoped service instead of transient `services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()`

Comment: When i am going to create a instance of class  var myClass = new YourServiceClass();

here we need to pass IHttpContextAccessor  as argument , so in this case how we can do it ??

Comment: @SajjadAliKhan: "When i am going to create a instance of class var myClass = new YourServiceClass(); here we need to pass IHttpContextAccessor as argument , so in this case how we can do it ??" DI will do that for you. Or do you have a different use case? BR